# Calculate date using different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns like this. The final df should contain a new column after taking the First_Date column and subtracting the corresponding unit and the corresponding value
`df = pd.DataFrame({"First_Date":[pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01")]*5, "Unit":['Years','Months','Days','Years','Days'], "Value":[1,2,2,3,5]})`

The output column should have the values:
`2019-01-01 2019-11-01 2020-12-29 2017-01-01 2020-12-27`

I have tried the timedelta module but the inputs to that is not accepting values from a different column. For example, it does not take

`df.apply(lambda x: x['First_Date']- timedelta(x['Unit'] = x['Value'])`

Answer (score 1):

Named arguments cannot be supplied from a variable as far as I am aware.

You could, however, create a one-hot encoding for your `Unit`-column and scale it by the `Value`-column to create a description of your delta:

```py
df_augmented = df.merge(pd.get_dummies(df.Unit).mul(df.Value, axis=0),
                        left_index=True, right_index=True)

  First_Date    Unit  Value  Days  Months  Years
0 2020-01-01   Years      1     0       0      1
1 2020-01-01  Months      2     0       2      0
2 2020-01-01    Days      2     2       0      0
3 2020-01-01   Years      3     0       0      3
4 2020-01-01    Days      5     5       0      0
```

Now, you can statically supply all values to the function (as in `years=df_augmented.Years, months=df_augmented.Months` etc) and all should be well.